# Amazon Linux AMI ec2 GUI / Remote Desktop

Tags: linux, user-interface, amazon-web-services

I know GUI is for the weak but unfortunately strictly using the terminal isn't an option for me. I have an instance of the Amazon Linux AMI and I have it all set up but I can't find a guide on how to get a GUI on Amazon and how to remote desktop/ VNC into it. I have seen stuff on how to do this for the Ubuntu instance but that is different from Amazon Linux AMI and I don't want to mess up my system or something like that.

So if anyone could point me to where I can find how to do this or tell me how I'd appreciate it

Comment: [Take a look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984107/how-can-i-connect-to-amazon-linux-instance-using-remote-desktop-from-windows-7).

Comment: the video shown here is for ubuntu will this still work for Amazon Linux AMi?

Comment: Not sure, as I haven't done this myself; give it a try!

Comment: I tried it says "no package vnc4server available" also figured out to replace apt-get with yum.

Answer (score 9):

No, you can't. Amazon Linux does not have a Repo for X-server packages. Also, It was meant to be used for Server side roles and hence all he X related stuff is not available.

Consider using `Ubuntu` OR `RHEL` ami where you can configure X environment manually by following [this](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/AWS/AWS_Tips/AWS_Management/AWS_12.shtml) and [this](http://xmodulo.com/2013/06/how-to-set-up-ubuntu-desktop-vm-on-amazon-ec2.html).

Comment: just came across https://www.nomachine.com/AR07K00676  nomachine is not support on ubuntu 12.04 or later

Answer (score 4):

You can set up VNC server for your EC2 Linux boxes. There are tutorials for ubuntu (xrdp) and RHEL (VNC server) in the following websites.

http://devopscube.com/setup-gui-for-amazon-ec2-linux/

http://www.comtechies.com/2013/02/how-to-set-up-gui-on-amazon-ec2-ubuntu.html

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

You can install a GUI just using one command

> sudo amazon-linux-extras install mate-desktop1.x

Comment: Okay, but how do I access "mate desktop"?  Note: I am using Amazon linux2 virtual machine (using VMWare) on my Windows laptop.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a Remmina VNC as a client on my Ubuntu.
If you need a Windows client - then you have a plenty of options - RealVNC, TightVNC, TigerVNC, UltraVNC