# How to install GUI (Desktop) in Amazon Linux 2 AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, user-interface, desktop

I am trying to install GUI on my Amazon Linux 2 AMI. I tried several solutions like GNNOME and Mate Desktop, but when I try to install desktop by group list I get a warning:

> group Desktop does not exist or GNOME does not exist.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269204/amazon-linux-ami-ec2-gui-remote-desktop

Comment: Yes i checked it but i the approach is not working i want the GUI for linux 2 ami.

Answer (score 2):

This is now supported.

See this article in the AWS knowledge base:
[How do I install a GUI on my Amazon EC2 instance running Amazon Linux 2?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-2-install-gui/)

> Last updated: 2021-04-20
> **I want to install a graphical user interface (GUI) in my Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) instance running Amazon Linux 2. How do I do this?**

> ### Short description
>
> To install a GUI on your EC2 Linux instance, do the following:
>
> 1. Install the MATE desktop environment. MATE is a lightweight GUI based on GNOME 2 available as an extra for Amazon Linux 2. The Amazon Linux 2 offering of [Amazon WorkSpaces](https://aws.amazon.com/workspaces/) uses MATE. For more information about MATE, see the [MATE desktop environment website](https://mate-desktop.org/).
> 2. Install a virtual network computing (VNC) service, such as TigerVNC. For more information about TigerVNC, see the [tigervnc.org website](https://tigervnc.org/).
> 3. Connect to the GUI using the VNC.
> 4. (Optional) Install a web browser, such as Firefox or Chromium. For more information on Firefox, see the [mozilla.org website](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/). For more information on Chromium, see the [chromium.org website](https://www.chromium.org/).
>    *Note:* These instructions apply only to Amazon Linux 2. To confirm the version that you're running, run the following command:

> ```
> cat /etc/os-release
> ```